# Bootstrap img-responsive causing hyperlink to span entire column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The following code creates a hyperlink image.

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top: 25px;">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <a href="http://www.aibd.org" target="_blank">
            <img src="/images/aibd_logo.png" class="img-responsive" style="padding: 5px; height: 125px; background-color: #ffffff; margin: 0 auto;" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the div spans all 12 Bootstrap columns.  The image is contained in a hyperlink.  I'm using the "img-responsive" class on the image.  The "margin: 0 auto" causes the image to be centered in the column.

Here's the problem:

When you hover over the image in the browser, you get the "finger" cursor as you would expect.  However, if you move your cursor off of the image, to the left or to the right but still within the same Bootstrap row, your cursor will still give you the "finger" even though your cursor isn't on top of the image.  And if you click, it will navigate to the linked page.  It is still recognizing the hyperlink even though you are no longer hovering over the image.

You can see this behavior if you go to http://new.integriby.com and you hover over the AIBD logo towards the bottom of the page.

Is this a bug in Bootstrap?  Does anyone know of a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug in bootstrap, this is the expected behavior.  img-responsive assigns the img `display:block`, which makes it a block element.  You could assign your image `display:inline-block;` and remove the margin:auto and get the same sizing effect without forcing it to be a block element.  Then set text-align: center on your div to center the `a`.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use `text-center` on `col-xs-12` (actually you don't need row and column in this case, simple `div` would be enough) without `img-responsive` class (you could apply `max-width: 125px; max-height: 125px` if you consider displaying it on fingernail ;).

Answer (score 0):

Please check the insert inline CSS codes.
Use  style="cursor: default;" for the link and cursor: pointer; for the image.

I hope you can see the solution.

```html
<div class="row" style="padding-top: 25px;">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <a href="http://www.aibd.org" target="_blank" style="cursor: default;">
            <img src="images/aibd_logo.png" class="img-responsive" style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px; height: 125px; background-color: #ffffff; margin: 0 auto;" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```